# MySql tree style alternative

Tags: mysql

After 4 years of using MySql for most php projects, I'm starting to realize that the way mysql stores data is not something I particularly like.
So I'm wondering if there are any "**tree style**" alternatives out there that store data in a fashion like this "user/blog/blogposts/blogpost1" for example?
Ideally it should be free and supported by php.
I've tried some googling but it has been rather fruitles.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you will like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB ?

Answer (score 0):

http://openquery.com/graph/doc

Available as plugin for MySQL

From the site:

> The Open Query GRAPH computation
>   engine, or OQGRAPH  as the engine
>   itself is called, allows you to handle
>   hierarchies (tree structures) but also
>   complex graphs (nodes having many
>   connections in several directions).
>
> [...]
>
> In the MySQL server infrastructure,
>   OQGRAPH is a storage engine, just like
>   MyISAM, InnoDB, MEMORY and NDBCluster,
>   to name a few.

Comment: This looks a little complicated for what I had in mind, are there any xml style alternatives? :)

Answer (score 0):

[eXist-db](http://exist.sourceforge.net/) or [Sedna](http://modis.ispras.ru/sedna/) are both XML databases.